# Tkinter: Making 'classes' for buttons and labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, pretty much I have many different buttons and labels in a tkinter frame, and I all want them to have similar properties. Lets say I want all of them to have a foreground color of red, and have a transparent background (can I even do that? This transparent background is just for buttons.)

Can I have a `class` for buttons (I think this is in ttk, but it would be preferable if it wasn't) similar to css that would make all my buttons and labels have red text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could extend `Button` class and define its properties as you wish. For example:

```
from tkinter import *


class MyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self['bg'] = 'red'



root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

my_button = MyButton(root, text='red button')
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Now that I see it, I feel like its obvious. Thanks!

Comment: But how would I do this within a class? would I do self.MyButton()?

Comment: @Kevin but do what within a class? pack the button?

Comment: As in make this a subclass of a parent class Application, and then have Application have MyButton() stuff. Sorry, I'm not really that great at this.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

class My_Button(Button):
    def __init__(self, text, row, col, command, color=None, **kwargs):
        self.text = text
        self.row = row
        self.column = col
        self.command = command
        self.color = color
        super().__init__()
        self['bg'] = self.color
        self['text'] = self.text
        self['command'] = self.command
        self.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column)


def dothings():
    print('Button class worked')

window = Tk()
window.title("Test Button Class")
window.geometry('400x200')

btn1 = My_Button("Click Me", 0, 0, dothings, 'green')

window.mainloop()
```