# Creating Buttons that toggles Reliefs on click with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a class of Raised Buttons that would toggle their Relief between "Raised" and "Sunken" for every click.

I managed to find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050068/tkinter-making-classes-for-buttons-and-labels) on how to create a Class of customized Buttons. It worked well on its own to make the custom buttons:

```
class TypButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self["relief"] = "raised"
```

Then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152307/how-to-create-a-tkinter-toggle-button) on how to make the Reliefs toggle on buttons:

```
def toggle_btn():
    if TypButton("relief")[-1] == "raised":
        TypButton.config(relief="sunken")
    else:
        TypButton.config(relief="raised")
```

And here is the TypButton widget with the command to toggle:

```
btn_this = TypButton(root, text="This", command=toggle_btn()).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I ran the code:

```
`...line 17, in __init__
    Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`

`...Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2679, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)`

`...Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2595, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)`

`...Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2564, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk`

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'`
```

Attempts to add "tk"s anywhere resulted in errors outside of my skillset.

I tried changing `if TypButton("relief")[-1] == "raised":` to
`if TypButton["relief"] == "raised":`
and this error appeared:

```
`line 26, in main
    btn_this = TypButton(root, text="This", command=toggle_btn()).grid(row=0, column=0)`

`line 21, in toggle_btn
    if TypButton["relief"] == "raised":`

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`
```

Honestly, I do not know how to fix either error.

Mostly my suspicions are on the Toggle function since the Class worked well.

I wanted the code ***to check if the relief is Raised or not and continue with the function***. Most posts I found online had too much on the side or are not helping my case.

Apologies for the long post.

### Addendum:

I tried the following which accomplishes the toggling issue. However I am going to create over 10 of these buttons which have different names (as shown in example) and I cannot afford to manually type in all the different names into the toggle function.

In this case, `That` button affects `This` button instead of itself:

```py
global is_on
is_on = False

def toggle_btn():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        btn_this.config(relief="raised")
        is_on = False
    else:
        btn_this.config(relief="sunken")
        is_on = True

btn_this = Button(root, text="This", command=toggle_btn)
btn_this.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn_that = Button(root, text="That", command=toggle_btn)
btn_that.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: The first step of debugging is to find out where the error is happening. Can you show us the line where the error happens? Have a look over that line and the lines surrounding it and you might even spot the error yourself

Comment: I have added in the error lines as requested, hopefully that helps. I figure that I might not be understanding the syntax enough for these functions even if I have a clear objective of what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Ok so the first one looks like a bug in tkinter. You should make sure your version of Python is up to date (latest is 3.10.5). The second one seems to be due to you attempting to modify the properties of the `TypButton` class rather than an instance of `TypeButton`.

Comment: My Python is up to date it seems. And I'm unsure what a `TypeButton` is, mainly since `TypButton` is the class name I chose and it didn't show up when I typed it in PyCharm.

Comment: For your case, it is better to use `Checkbutton` widget with `indicatoron=0` instead of normal `Button` widget, then you don't need the `toggle_btn()` function at all.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out now. Hopefully it can do things as similar as a normal `Button` widget can. If not, I might have to return here.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a Checkbutton widget as has been mentioned. However, to illustrate how this could also be done to extend a Button widget class with additional event handling here is a demo with the custom class renamed as `ToggleButton`.

```
"""
Demo creation of a derived tk.Button with extra event handling.
Someone wanted to have a button that locks down or up as you click it.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/73193733/291641

Better off using a Checkbutton(indicatoron=False)

Note: the default event handling for a tk.Button manipulates the relief
value to create the 'clicked' visual effect. This means to override this
the custom class must apply it's relief setting after the command invocation
is completed (ie at the application handler).
"""

import sys
import tkinter as tk


class ToggleButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        # Add a custom property "toggle"
        self.toggle = False
        if "toggle" in kwargs:
            self.toggle = kwargs["toggle"]
            del kwargs["toggle"]
        super(ToggleButton, self).__init__(master=master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Add a custom bind class (before the Button class)
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(bindtags.index("Button"), "ToggleButton")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))

        # Include a class invoke handler.
        master.bind_class("ToggleButton", '<Button-1>', ToggleButton.on_invoke)

    @staticmethod
    def on_invoke(event):
        event.widget.toggle = not event.widget.toggle


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(master=master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.checked = tk.IntVar(master)
        f = tk.Frame(self)
        self.button = ToggleButton(f, text="Toggle", command=self.on_click)
        self.check = tk.Checkbutton(f, text="Checked", indicatoron=0, command=self.on_checked, variable=self.checked)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.check.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        vs = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=vs.set)
        f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.text.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        vs.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def log(self, msg, tags=None):
        self.text.insert(tk.END, msg, tags)
        self.text.see(tk.END)

    def on_click(self):
        state = self.button.toggle
        relief = "sunken" if state else "raised"
        self.button.configure(relief=relief)
        self.log(f"Toggle state is {state}\n")

    def on_checked(self):
        self.log(f"Checked state is {self.checked.get()}\n")


def main(args=None):
    global app
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    try:
        import idlelib.pyshell
        sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], "-n"]
        root.bind("<Control-F2>", lambda ev: idlelib.pyshell.main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    root.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```